# How can I start the droid vnc server (start apk and thenc click on start button) from my android app

Tags: android, autostart, vnc-server

When a user starts my application on Android, I want that Droid VNC server be started automatically. I know using intent we can start other APKs. Here when I run the Droid application it shows screen with Start button. Without clicking the Start button the Droid VNC server does not start.

Can either of the following three possible.

1. From my app can I trigger that start button on VNC server got clicked somehow; or
2. Can the Droid VNC server automatically opens in the start mode (without need of clicking on start button); or
3. Lets say my app starts VNC apk and user gets VNC screen and user clicks on the start button on it. After clicking the start button (vnc started) can control automatically come back to my app (my app come on foreground).

Regards,
Bhavdeep